# Select/deselect TextField in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, selection, textfield

I have a project, that contains 5 textfields, and the problem is that when the program starts, the first textfield is always "selected" with a cursor in it?

[image]

How should I remove the selection? I have tried..
1. textfield.clear() / it only clear the content, but it is empty by default
2. textfield.setDisabled(true) / I can't select or edit it at all
3. textfield.setEditable(false) / I can't edit
4. textfield.deselect() / actually this doesn't do anything

Any idea?

Comment: the correct term is _focused_ .. what else should be if not the first?

Comment: I don't want to be selected any of them. The user should be manually click in which he/she wants.

Comment: you should add all the necessary info to your question :) Same hold for your follow-up question (which you might post as another question) .. best withe a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Try `root.requestFocus();` in the parent.

Comment: Thanks, and which method should I call in case of TreeItems, where there isn't requestFocus()?